# Object not showing in mirror reflection

Tags: mirror, reflection, mirror-modifier

How to solve the problem where my object (floor of the room) is not showing in mirror reflection. I am using Cycles.
Thank you for your answers.

[image]

Comment: Hi, good to see you again!  Your screenshot doesn't seem to be showing the problem, could you annotate it to be more clear?  And you'll recall it's sometimes a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem (maybe with all models deleted except the floor and mirror).  The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files:  https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: I took this screenshot because you can see that the floor isn’t reflecting. There is just the reflection of the HDRI image (grass). Other reflective objects are also reflecting just the HDRI image and not the floor.

Comment: Here is the link to my docment. Thank you for your help.  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Pd0b201A" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Pd0b201A/)

Answer (score 1):

In the Properties Editor > Object Properties tab > Visibility > Ray Visibility the default is to have all boxes checked.  On your FLOOR object you have unchecked Diffuse, Glossy, Volume Scatter, and Shadow -- Glossy seems to be what's causing this, with it checked the floor seems to be reflecting okay:

[image]

I'd keep Diffuse checked as well, but honestly it doesn't seem to be causing a problem here.